# converting milliseconds to string date dd MMM YYYY and using it in LIKE Clause

Tags: postgresql

I have stored a date in milliseconds in table  as follow:

```
table: person
columns: id,name,dob
```

want to select person details based on given dob

```
Eg. SELECT id,name,to_date(dob) as dob FROM person WHERE dob LIKE '10 Jun 1991'
```

here function to_date() should select the milliseconds and convert to format '10 Jun 1991'

Comment: Do **not** use `LIKE` on date or timestamp values. It's for strings only. You should use `where ... = date '1991-06-10'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your timestamp in milliseconds to the desired format with the following if the milliseconds are measured from the UNIX epoch on:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(dob / 1000.0), 'DD Mon YYYY')
```

Comment: what if i have to do exactly reverse ,means i have string date 10 Jun 2018 and want it to convert into milliseconds, I need this while inserting data into table

Comment: Then use `to_timestamp` with the appropriate format and `extract` to get the seconds since the epoch.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL

```
SELECT id, name, FROM_UNIXTIME(dob / 1000) FROM person
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

For Postgres:

```
SELECT id, name, to_timestamp(dob / 1000) FROM person
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Actually i am using postgres

Comment: Sorry, missed it. So you can try SELECT id,name, to_timestamp(dob / 1000) FROM person

Comment: what if i have to do exactly reverse ,means i have string date 10 Jun 2018 and want it to convert into milliseconds, I need this while inserting data into tabl

Comment: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. For REDSHIFT. Any idea?